# Django: How to get current user in admin forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In Django's `ModelAdmin`, I need to display forms customized according to the permissions a user has. Is there a way of getting the current user object into the form class, so that i can customize the form in its `__init__` method?

I think saving the current request in a thread local would be a possibility but this would be my last resort because I'm thinking it is a bad design approach.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here is what i did recently for a Blog:

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogPostForm

    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(BlogPostAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user
        return form
```

I can now access the current user in my `forms.ModelForm` by accessing `self.current_user`

Comment: If `form = BlogPostForm`, what shall `get_form` actually return? A BlogPostForm or the ModelForm of the parent class of BlogPostAdmin...? How will BlogPostForm get used if you use get_form?

Comment: @AndrewBarrett not for class, and not dangerous

Comment: @AndrewBarrett this should be safe because we are attaching the `current_user` to a form instance and a new one is newly created for each request (hence `request` being passed as a variable to this method).

Comment: @Joshmaker Yeah for sure, not sure what I was smoking two years ago, have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 22):

Joshmaker's answer doesn't work for me on Django 1.7. Here is what I had to do for Django 1.7:

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogPostForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(BlogPostAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user
        return form
```

For more details on this method, please see [this relevant Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form)

Comment: how the code-snippet is different from the one shared by Joshmaker?

Answer (score 9):

This use case is documented at [ModelAdmin.get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form)

> [...] if you wanted to offer additional fields to superusers, you could swap in a different base form like so:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs['form'] = MySuperuserForm
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

---

If you just need to save a field, then you could just override [ModelAdmin.save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I found a solution that works for me: To create a `ModelForm` Django uses the admin's `formfield_for_db_field`-method as a callback.
So I have overwritten this method in my admin and pass the current user object as an attribute with every field (which is probably not the most efficient but appears cleaner to me than using threadlocals:

```
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        field = super(MyAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        field.user = kwargs.get('request', None).user
        return field
```

Now I can access the current user object in the forms `__init__` with something like:

```
    current_user=self.fields['fieldname'].user
```

Comment: This is an `AttributeError`: `kwargs.get('request', None).user`

Answer (score 4):

stumbled upon same thing and this was first google result on my page.Dint helped, bit more googling and worked!!

Here is how it works for me (django 1.7+) :

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # This is important to have because this provides the
    # "request" object to "clean" method
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(SomeAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)
        form.request = request
        return form

class SomeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ["A", "B"]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SomeAdminForm, self).clean()
        logged_in_email = self.request.user.email #voila
        if logged_in_email in ['abc@abc.com']:
            raise ValidationError("Please behave, you are not authorised.....Thank you!!")
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way you can solve this issue is by using Django currying which is a bit cleaner than just attaching the request object to the form model.

```
from django.utils.functional import curry

class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogPostForm

    def get_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = super(BlogPostAdmin, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)
        return curry(form, current_user=request.user)
```

This has the added benefit making your **init** method on your form a bit more clear as others will understand that it's being passed as a kwarg and not just randomly attached attribute to the class object before initialization.

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.current_user = kwargs.pop('current_user')
       super(BlogPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I liked this but sadly doesn't work as downstream the code expects a form class and not a curry function. Doing this results in the following error "'function' object has no attribute 'base_fields'"

Comment: Could one add it to the kwargs directly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function which acts as a proxy to the form class, allowing us to inject the request, on the form instance, so that we can access it in the clean methods.

By using a solution like the below one (get_form_class_with_request), you isolate the request injection to the moment of form instance creation. This ensures that each form instance has its own request data, reducing the risk of conflicts and unexpected behavior caused by shared state.

```
def get_form_class_with_request(
        form_class: type[forms.ModelForm], request: HttpRequest
) -> Callable[[tuple[Any, ...], dict[str, Any]], ModelForm]:
    
        def init_form(*args, **kwargs) -> ModelForm:
            form_instance = form_class(*args, **kwargs)
            form_instance.request = request
            form_instance.current_user = request.user
    
            return form_instance
    
        init_form.base_fields = form_class.base_fields
    
        return init_form


class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = YourForm    
    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form_proxy = get_form_class_with_request(form, request)

        return form_proxy
```

Overall, it's a best practice to keep request-specific data within the request scope and avoid storing it directly in form classes or other shared objects to maintain proper isolation and prevent potential issues.