# why save_model method doesn't work in admin.StackedInline?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a similar problem as a previously solved problem of mine, except this time solution doesn't seem to work:

[How to auto insert the current user when creating an object in django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991365/how-to-auto-insert-the-current-user-when-creating-an-object-in-django-admin)

Previously i used to override the save_model to stamp the user submitting the article. Now i need to do the same for comments, it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The saving isn't done in the InlineAdmin's `save_form`, you have to look at `save_formsets` in the ModelAdmin to which the inlines belong:

```
 class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyInlineAdmin,.....]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        formset.save()
        if not change:
            for f in formset.forms:
                obj = f.instance 
                obj.user = request.user
                obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to provide some more substantial example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477319/how-to-get-the-django-current-login-user

Comment: Are you sure: if not change: is correct?  Shouldn't it be if change:?  Thanks a bunch for your example!!!  Up voted.

Comment: @LukeDupin I think this is correct. As written it would only set the user when the inline object is created but not on updates.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset