# How to create separate folder for each user in django and let user upload file in that folder?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to let each user upload a text file such that he can see only his uploaded file. I also want his uploaded files to get stored in his own folder like home/ubuntu/documents/username/

my models.py looks like this -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os

class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('documents', instance.owner.username, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

Comment: Yeah, but what is the problem? What's not working?

Comment: And why would you want to store files in `home/ubuntu/documents`? What's wrong with `media` folder of your project?

Comment: @xyres ok it would help even if you could tell me how to do that in media folder, please?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Sorry about the last *faux pas*.

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return 'documents/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.username, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

Also, [see documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload%5Fto) for another example.

---

### Notes

1. Do configure `MEDIA_ROOT` path in your settings file. This is where the files will be stored in.
2. Don't forget to write another method which will change the name of the folder of a user whenever he/she will change his/her username.
3. Alternative to Point 2 above will be using `pk` instead of username. But it's up to you.

Comment: Hey @xyres when i ran this code, i got following error -

    NameError: name 'get_upload_path' is not defined

Comment: @VipulVaibhaw Sorry, made a mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: It now says You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'owner' to document without a default.
I am sorry, I am new to django, so getting a lot of problems.

Comment: @VipulVaibhaw Does your `Document` model has `user` field, or any other `ForeignKey` linking to `User` model? If unclear, just post your whole `Document` model in your question. I'll figure out.

Comment: I have posted whole models.py file here, no user in Document model.

Comment: @VipulVaibhaw Well, then you'll have to add a `ForeignKey` to `User` model in your `Document` model. Otherwise you won't know which user has uploaded what file. Instead of `owner`, write `user = ForeignKey(User, null=True)`. I've updated the code in answer, too.

Comment: I ran your code but now I am getting this error -

AttributeError at /list/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username' 
/home/ubuntu/test_site.com/testproject/testapp/models.py in get_upload_path, line 22

Comment: @VipulVaibhaw When you upload a file, you'll have to choose a user too. That's how you'll know which file belongs to which user. If you're doing this in admin, this should be easy. If not, then that's a totally different question.

Comment: but why to choose a user? the user logged in should be able to upload his file in his own folder.

Comment: @VipulVaibhaw Yes I get what you're saying. That's why I said it's a different question. This question might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991365/how-to-auto-insert-the-current-user-when-creating-an-object-in-django-admin