# Django admin model field set to current user

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a model with field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_by = models.ForeignKeyField(User)
```

In my admin:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ("name",)
    fields = ("name",)
```

Here I don't want `created_by` in admin while adding MyModel. I want it to be set to current user like `created_by = request.user`

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to auto insert the current user when creating an object in django admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991365/how-to-auto-insert-the-current-user-when-creating-an-object-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already set [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) so that `created_by` does not appear in form in the Django admin.

Now you need to override [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), and set the user before saving new objects.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("name",)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            # the object is being created, so set the user
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: didnt worked for me... keeping both fields and tried seeing request.user in field. It dont appear

Comment: Should I not return anything? after the model is saved?

Comment: Thank you.. I had to make model field to null and blank to true

Comment: No, `save_model` does not have to return anything.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set `blank` and `null` to `True`. I tested the above code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To do that override the `save_model` method and set the `created_by` field to the current user.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ("name",)
    fields = ("name",)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):             
        if not change: 
        # can use this condition also to set 'created_by'    
        # if not getattr(obj, 'created_by', None):            
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: I didnt see user in my form. When I try to save without created_by it gives error that is this field is required

Comment: @Alasdair updated it to check if  `obj` has `created_by` attribute set.

Comment: @gamer Try adding `null=True` and `blank=True`  to `created_by`.

Comment: The line in the comment `if not getattr(self, 'created_by', None)` won't work, because `self` is the `ModelAdmin` instance, not the object. You could test `if obj.created_by` instead, but that's not quite the same as testing whether the object is being created.

Comment: Sorry it was `obj`  above. Updated the ans and yes checking via `created` is better.