# Django Integrity Error when adding post in a form that excludes a foreign key

Tags: django

the cause of the error is simple. The admin site asks me to select or browse user when I am logged in. So,  I excluded the field to hide it in the admin form. It generates the integrity error.

How do I tell django to attach the currently logged in user (in the admin area) as the creator of the object?

I have seen a few posts that require me to make use of forms.py but I want to use the default admin template. Where do I make the edits at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Note that this will change the user every time the object is updated in future. If you only want to set the user once when the object is created, then [check the value of change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366720/django-admin-model-field-set-to-current-user/31366901#31366901).

Comment: @Alasdair true dat.

Comment: Thanks both. Works like a charm and Alasdaiir...thanks for the added tip. Helpful.