# Django request.user is model, for admin and normal user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-request

I want to autocomplete 2 fields:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='created_by')
updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='updated_by')
```

for normal users and for django admin.

If for normal users I can use get request.user from my view(found some solutions here on the site),but this is not the case for admin/staff because I don't control the views, so I'm searching for a solution at the Model level by overwriting the save function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by')

updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='updated_by')
```

Then in your view, you can do this :

```
form.created_by = request.user
form.updated_by = request.user
```

It's going to autocomplete by the current user who made the action.

May be I didn't understant your question, so may be this is what you're looking for : [How to auto insert the current user when creating an object in django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991365/how-to-auto-insert-the-current-user-when-creating-an-object-in-django-admin)

Comment: with the view I know, but in admin I don't control the view. The link helped me, I modified the answer from that post, to make a distinction between when is created and when is changed

Answer (score 1):

May be the solution with default user by Middleware help you.

[django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786764/8060120)

Comment: post relevant part of the solution in the question itself. Link only answers are not acceptable

Comment: thanks, but is a 8 year old thread so I thought there is something better for Django 1.11; using a middleware means that I push it everywhere and I don't really want that

Answer (score 0):

is pretty simple, just add to your field: editable=False 
Like this:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, editable=False, related_name='created_by')
```

Comment: my need to get request.user in both normal model and admin model/form, nothing to do with  "editable=False". If I don't get this info the field/foreign key will be empty/blank/null, which will give an error