# Django - session key of actuall logged user, not possible to get from request

Tags: python, django, forms, request, session-cookies

How to get the session_key in form Class? It is not possible to get the request parameter to do something like this : `request.user`

I've got this situation, and I need to pass to function `get_user` session_key which is also
not possible to retrieve from request.

```
class CustomEntryAdminForm(EntryAdminForm):

def get_user(session_key):
    session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
    uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    return user


categories = MPTTModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label=_('Categories'), required=False,
        queryset=Category.objects.filter(groups__in=get_user('uwry5olhemchxnmwa36v10zt2bg9zeci').groups.all()),
        widget=MPTTFilteredSelectMultiple(_('categories'), False,
                                      attrs={'rows': '10'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pass user as keyword argument to your form. You do not need to jump through hoops and load active session key from request and then load user from decoded session. All you need to do is:

in view:

```
myform = MyFormClass(user= request.user)
```

in form:

```
class MyFormClass(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(MyFormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['categories'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(groups__in = self.user.groups.all())
```

NB! not complete working code. I just wanted  to show you how you can use the self.user in queryset.

Comment: It's not possible to make myform = MyFormClass(user= request.user), because i've got this code in class CustomEntryAdmin(EntryAdmin) in admin.py, and request is not recognize

Comment: so what, you can override admin page forms also - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form. And if this is not enough you can also override the views and templates of admin page. But i think you should probably consider another approach if it looks like you need to override too much.

Comment: I've got in my admin.py def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): and how do i get self.user from my form,  kwargs.pop('user', None) doesn't work

Comment: Check this page out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864955/django-how-to-get-current-user-in-admin-forms