# Django: Current User Id for ModelForm Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want for filter a ModelChoiceField with the current user. I found a solution very close that I want to do, but I dont understand
[Django: How to get current user in admin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864955/django-how-to-get-current-user-in-admin-forms)

The answer accepted says

"I can now access the current user in my forms.ModelForm by accessing self.current_user"

--admin.py

```
class Customer(BaseAdmin):
    form = CustomerForm
    
    def get_form(self, request,obj=None,**kwargs):
        form = super(Customer, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user
        return form
```

--forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    default_tax =   forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=fa_tax_rates.objects.filter(tenant=????)
    )

    class Meta:
        model   = fa_customers
```

How do I get the current user on modelchoice queryset(tenant=????)
How do I call the self.current_user in the modelform(forms.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `__init__` constructor of the `CustomerForm`:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['default_tax'].queryset = 
                        fa_tax_rates.objects.filter(tenant=self.current_user))
```

Queryset in the form field definition can be safely set to `all()` or `none()`:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    default_tax = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=fa_tax_rates.objects.none())
```

Comment: it raises an error: Exception Value: 
type object 'fa_customersForm' has no attribute 'fields'
Exception Location: /Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/myinvo/myinvoapp/admin.py in get_form, line 44

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `ModelAdmin.get_form()` returns not the form instance but a form class.  You can access that class property from the `__init__` constructor. See the corrected answer.

Comment: So frustrated, something that should be simple it's not. code Exception Type: AttributeError Exception Value: 'fa_customersForm' object has no attribute 'current_user' code Where should be the init? ModelForm or ModelAdmin? I have saw examples with view isnt it posible create without a view? I'm using the default admin

Comment: `__init__` should be in the `CustomerForm`. And `current_user` attribute is set in the `Customer.get_form()` method.

Comment: Thanks A lot. Urrrra!!!!!! I'm going to detail that I do, I felt confused because in some examples show get_form and another init but not both

Comment: 1.- Define the model
--model.pyclass fa_customers(models.Model):
        tenant              =   models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
        name                =   models.CharField(max_length=100)
        default_tax         =   models.ForeignKey(fa_tax_rates,null=True,blank=True)
    ...
    class fa_tax_rates(models.Model):
        tenant      =   models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True) 
        tax_code    =   models.CharField(max_length=25) 
        rate        =   models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.01)])

Comment: 2.- Add the model in your admin, passing the user using get_form
-- admin.py
    
     class Customer(BaseAdmin):
        form = CustomerForm
        
        def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
            form = super(Customer, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
            form.current_user = request.user
            return form

Comment: 3.- Define your for in forms.py getting the current user through __init__ passed by get_form in admin.py

--forms.py

    class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['default_tax'].queryset = fa_tax_rates.objects.filter(tenant=self.current_user)
        
        class Meta:
            model   = fa_customers

Answer (score 1):

Just to sum up the solution because it was very hard for me to make this work and understand the accepted answer

In admin.py

```
class MyModelForm (forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
    super (MyModelForm ,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    #retrieve current_user from MyModelAdmin
    self.fields['my_model_field'].queryset = Staff.objects.all().filter(person_name = self.current_user)
```

#The person name in the database must be the same as in Django User, otherwise use something like person_name__contains

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm 

    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user #get current user only accessible in MyModelAdminand pass it to MyModelForm
        return form
```