# How to fix, limit_choices_to cannot be a ForeignKey in Django?

Tags: python, django

I've a snip of code like following:

### models.py

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Note(models.Model):
    create_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    notebook=models.ForeignKey(Notebook, on_delete = models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to = {'owner' : create_user})
```

---

But I'm getting an error that limit_users_to cannot be a Foreign Key.
I want to users to select only notebooks they have created while writing a note, but now users can select other's notebook while limit_choices_to is not set.
And notebook must be ForeignKey.
What can i do?

Comment: Sounds to me that this restriction should be done at forms level and not at models. Because it depends on request (logged in user). Also `create_user` looks like unnecessary field if `owner` and `create_user` are same.

Comment: Why would the Note.notebook FK point to a User? and not to a Notebook? In any case, if you have two FK pointing to the same model (here: User) then specify the related_name attribute of the FKs. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583327/django-model-with-2-foreign-keys-from-the-same-table

Comment: @anupsabraham Can you give me an example how can I make such restrictions in forms level?

Comment: @PalashBauri I don't understand your model now. I was thinking `notebook` is a FK to your `Notebook` model until rollinger's comment. You need to do a little more for us to be able to answer your question. Do you have a form created where user can enter these details?

Comment: @anupsabraham sorry I fixed the mistake. Now Note.notebook FK points to the correct thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Current User Id for ModelForm Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038599/django-current-user-id-for-modelform-admin)

Comment: @rollinger I fixed the Note.notebook mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that in the View when creating a Note

form.py

```
from .models import Note
from django.forms import ModelForm

class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Note
```

view.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .form import NoteForm
from .models import Note, Notebook

class NoteCreateView(CreateView):
    model=Note
    form_class=NoteForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(NoteCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        # Thats the solution:
        form.fields['notebook'].queryset = Notebook.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return form
```

Comment: What is the wished behavior for notebooks created by the user, which contain no notes? Should these appear on the list or not?

Comment: Have to appear there otherwise you never would be able to add a note to any notebook. This is also out of scope of the question.

Comment: It’s not clear from the users question. You’re totally right, that’s the expected behavior. I just wondered if that was what Palash Bauri wants. Else your queryset needs to change. I don’t see how this is out of scope (but that discussion is really out of scope).