# Django downloading excel file return object name instead of excel file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a website where we download a xl file i have my view as below instead of returning the excel file its returning the text file with name of the object inside it how do i solve this

**views.py**:

```
def my_view(request):
 obj = model.objects.first()
    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=' 
  application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                )
    return response
```

**urls.py**:

```
path('temo/fill',views.my_view,name = 'my-view')
```

**models.py**

```
class Model(BaseModel, SingletonModel):
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='',
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator([''])]
    )
    person_uploaded = models.ForeignKey(
        'somemodel',
        related_name='s',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        )
```

**admin.py**:

```
@admin.register(tTemplate)
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('file','person_uploaded',)
    readonly_fields = ('person_uploaded',)

    def save(self, request):
        if not self.id:
            self.person_uploaded = request.user
        super().save()
```

Comment: Please provide your ``model``

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Bro i should autofill the person_uploaded name according to the user logged in and it should show that in the admin site but in my case for the code in admin.py its showing (-) unser persom_uploaded in admin site how can i acheive this?

Comment: You can pass ``person_uploaded=request.user`` inside your upload function

Comment: @AnkitTiwari There is no upload function here i am uploading in  the admin page directly

Comment: I have added the changed my code check once i have added admin.py file

Comment: Hello @Itriedit check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764294/14457833

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241723/discussion-between-itriedit-and-ankit-tiwari).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj = Plate.objects.first() # this will return you object
```

in objects there are multiple attributes there you've to get only your file attribute like this

```
@api_view(['GET',])
def my_view(request):
    obj = Plate.objects.first()
    response = HttpResponse(obj.file, content_type=' 
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
  application/vnd.ms-excel')
    return response
```

Comment: I have edited my question please take a look

Comment: Hello @Itriedit check I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
file = model.objects.first() # here you are returning the entire object
```

instead of a file so you'll obviously get the object name instead of a xl file.
Mos importantly is the xl file inside your object